# How can I read multiple files from multiple directories into R for processing?

Tags: r, batch-file

I am running a simulation study and need to process and save the results from several text files. I have the data organized in such a way where there are sub directories and within each sub directory, I need to process and get individual results for 1000 data files. This is very easy to do in SAS using macros. However, I am new to R and cannot figure out how to do such. Below is what I am trying to accomplish.

```
DATA Folder-> DC1 -> DC1R1.txt ... DC1R1000.txt
              DC2 -> DC2R1.txt ... DC2R1000.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `list.files`. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+list.files

Answer (score 12):

I'm not near a computer with R right now, but read the help for file-related functions:

The `dir` function will list the files and directories. It has a recursive argument. 
`list.files` is an alias for `dir`. The `file.info` function will tell you (among other things) if a path is a directory and `file.path` will combine path parts.

The `basename` and `dirname` functions might also be useful.

Note that all these functions are vectorized.

**EDIT** Now at a computer, so here's an example:

```
# Make a function to process each file
processFile <- function(f) {
  df <- read.csv(f)
  # ...and do stuff...
  file.info(f)$size # dummy result
}

# Find all .csv files
files <- dir("/foo/bar/", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\.csv$")

# Apply the function to all files.
result <- sapply(files, processFile)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! @Tommy.....Your coding is working so far....fingers crossed....I have 768 data conditions with 1000 simulated files under each condition. It will take awhile to process, so I will give a status once finished.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to run the same analysis on each of the files, then you can access them in one shot using `list.files(recursive = T)`. This is assuming that you have already set your working directory to `Data Folder`. The `recursive = T` lists all files within subdirectories as well.

Comment: Thanks Ramnath. I have never list.files but will give it a try. Tommy's coding is working so far.

Answer (score 5):

`filenames <- list.files("path/to/files", recursive=TRUE)`
This will give you all the files residing under one folder and sub folders under it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl's `glob ()` function to get a list of files and send it to R using, e.g., [RSPerl](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPerl)'s interface.

Comment: Hi Ltamar. I am not familiar with Perl. I am a statistician and have never had the need to use such. Although....I hear it is quite powerful.